# Track someone through ID

Tags: soundcloud

How can I get someone's url throught user's ID on soundcloud ?
Soundcloud API has stopped working since 2017, so I have to do this way.

I have this ID :
591290625 => https://soundcloud.com/helennpham
What I am trying to get is something like this:
[www.soundcloud.com/591290625](http://www.soundcloud.com/591290625) or maybe [www.soundcloud.com/users/591290625](http://www.soundcloud.com/users/591290625)